# Node js, Dollar Sign, html, express

Tags: javascript

I just started using Node.js and learning web development but I'm a bit unclear on the meaning/function of some symbols/signs.

**For example, in the following code:**

```js
$(function() {
  $.getJSON('/data', function(data) {
    var $dataContainer = $('#data-container');

    if (data.error) {
      $dataContainer.html('Error! ' + data.error);
      return;
    }

    // Clear the loading message.
    $dataContainer.html('');

    data.records.forEach(function(record) {
      var $galleryCard = $('<div class="gallery-card" />');
      if (record.picture[0]) {
        // Just show the first picture, if it has one.
        $('<img />').attr('src', record.picture[0].url).appendTo($galleryCard);
      }
      var $label = $('<strong />').text(record.name);
      $galleryCard.append($label);
      $dataContainer.append($galleryCard);
    });
  });
});
```

Why is there a "**$**" before the function()? What about when the **$** is in front of ".getJSON", in front of the variable DataContainer, and infront of ('#data-container')? Also, what does the **#** infront of data-container mean?

Thank you!

Comment: 1. Read about jQuery. 2. Read about CSS selectors.

Comment: You might want to take a step back and spin through a tutorial or two first; it's quite a bit more efficient to actually learn some stuff on your own rather than asking about every single thing along the way. As mentioned, this is all jQuery so far (no NodeJS involved at all)--learn some JS and jQ then start asking questions.

Comment: `$` doesn't inherently mean anything, but lots of libraries use it as their main function name (e.g. jQuery -> `$` is a function. Open your console and run `console.log($)` or use the typeof operator etc...)

Comment: 1) `$` is a variable (jQuery). 2) `$` is still jQuery. 3) `#` means look for something with an ID of whatever is after the `#`; jQuery selectors (similar, but not identical, to CSS selectors, because IIRC jQ has some extensions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the code you're referring to is using jQuery: a JavaScript library that makes things like HTML document traversal and manipulation, event handling, animation, and Ajax much simpler.

The $ is, simply put, the shortcut to access the jQuery library. Syntax would be $(selector).action().

The # symbol you're referring to is a selector, particularly referring to id. Selectors allow you to select and manipulate different elements, in this case an element (possibly a div) with an id="data-container".

If you would like to read more about jQuery their website is: https://jquery.com/

To learn more about selectors, go here: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

what $ in your code means is alias of jQuery (which is a javascript library) object. (see [this](http://jquery.com/)).

In simpler words basically, your code has nothing to do with nodejs(server side javascript) but it is related to browser supported version of javascript.

Comment: ... maybe its `cheerioJs` :)

Comment: @JonasW. Not with `getJSON`, it isn't.